# Problem with % Error: Unrecognized object type in stargazer R package

Tags: r, stargazer

% Error: Unrecognized object type after sample code

***stargazer(ToothGrowth ~ supp, type = "text")***

What can be a reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

Stargazer is used to format regression results output, not to run the regression itself. So before calling `stargazer`, you need to create a regression object by calling the appropriate function. E.g.:

Step 1: `lm.obj <- lm(ToothGrowth~supp, data = YOUR.DF)`

Step 2: `stargazer(lm.obj, type="text")`

That should yield your expected results.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I missed that in my own code and sample one, PKR, Maciek